# What is the IDE for Visual basic?

Tags: visual-basic, visual-basic-6

So weird to ask and I am sorry for the this question. What is the IDE for Visual basic? I searched throughout the internet but I didnt find the nice information about visual basic and its IDE.

Comment: Visual Studio, or potentially the built in editor within the MS office application  you're using.

Comment: software recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic] (it's the same here as at Stack Overflow). See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: If the question were phrased better, it could be migrated to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about classic Visual Basic (not VB.net), right?. There was no separate IDE, the program was called "Visual Basic".

See the [Visual Basic Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic) page for a screenshot of the VB6 IDE

Answer (score 1):

You can use any version of Visual Studio (I.E Express, Professional, Ultimate) to write Visual Basic code. When you create a new project in Visual Studio, select Other Languages and then Visual Basic.

[image: Where to use the Visual Basic templates]

If you don't have the Professional or Ultimate versions of Visual Studio, the [Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) versions of Visual Studio are free and offer most of the functionality of the other versions.

Also, there is no *one* IDE for Visual Basic, but Visual Studio is the most popular IDE for that language. What I'm saying is, you could write VB code in Notepad and then compile it with a Terminal window.